# Do multiprocess in python cost at least 0.3s？

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have been trying to learn to use the multiprocessing module in python. I seem to find a little interesting fact in this module, if using pool() function to folk some sub-process, it seems no matter what kind of job every single process is doing, to finish all the process, it will cost at least 0.3s,for example, if I print something 16 times, it will cost very little time, but if I use 16 processes, and every process do a print once, it will cost 0.3s, I don't know if it is my code has some kind of error or what else, can somebody explain this to me, the code I use is down below:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
start = time.time()

def task():
    print('something')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Parent process %s.' % os.getpid())
    p = Pool(16)
    for i in range(17):
        p.apply_async(task)
    print('Waiting for all subprocesses done...')
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print('All subprocesses done.')
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

Comment: note that there is upto a [0.1 second timeout](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L406) when closing the pool.  not sure where the 300ms is coming from.  maybe you could measure more things like "time to create pool" and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That 300ms is just the amount of time your operating system takes to spawn a new process on your system. There's pretty much nothing you can do about that delay (except get a faster system) and it will always vary from system to system.

Answer (score 1):

Multiprocessing is generally used to take advantage of multiple cores. There is an overhead when it comes to spawning multiple processes. For small tasks, multiprocessing is usually slower.

Comment: So when it comes to some small tasks, how can I achieve parallel processing？

Comment: You might want to create batches and run the tasks in batches.

Answer (score 1):

0.3s is specific to your system with current environment. It can vary with:

- hardware
- N cores busy
- N running processes
- various process affinity
- etc

On the same system it can be happily cost even more than few seconds if you keep all the cores busy to such state the OS just can't manage to do it faster. Kind of like a fork bomb shows with its behavior slowly freezing or even halting the system.

Check your hardware, mainly CPU's physical cores and use e.g. `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` (or twice that amount depending on core threads) to achieve maximum efficiency. Otherwise, let's say you have 4 cores and you spawn 8 processes. That's 2 processes per single physical core, however your OS also needs to run somewhere, Python master process also requires something to run on and in case you have Chrome or Firefox Quantum open that's also a lot of processes.

If you close everything down and leave only your program (and OS obviously, preferably in text mode to get more resources) running, you might get a better performance.

Multiple processes also take some resources such as master process communicating with the slave processes e.g. [with sockets](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Modules/_multiprocessing/multiprocessing.c#L98) so there will always be *some* overhead over a single, single-threaded Python process.